# Regular octagons and diagonals proof

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Definition:

> A diagonal of a octagon is a line segment connecting any two
>   non-adjacent vertices.

Prove:

> Every vertex of the regular octagon will produce 2 diagonals that are
>   parallel to at least one side and 3 diagonals that are not parallel to
>   any side.

[image]

Comment: Well, if the octagonal is regular you can figure out what all the angles are equal to precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that regardless of approach, we need only investigate diagonals $1$, $2$, and $3$ because there is reflective symmetry over diagonal $3$.  Moreover, we only need to prove this fact for a single vertex due to rotational symmetry.

Now this probably isn't the most elegant, but one method would be to inscribe the octagon within a unit square:

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$[image]

We can imagine this square has its lower left vertex at the origin, and we can find the coordinates of the vertices of the octagon since the lengths $x$ and $y$ obey the following:

\begin{align}
&2x + y \ = \ 1 \qquad \ \quad \text{(It's a unit square)} \\
&2x^2 \ = \ y^2 \qquad \qquad \text{(From the Pythagorean theorem)}
\end{align}

With those coordinates, one can explicitly compute and compare the slopes of the diagonals and of the sides.

Comment: what do you mean by rotational symmetry? What has rotational symmetry? Do you mean regardless of which arbitrary vertex we start with to construct line 1,2,3,4,5, this proofish holds?

Comment: If you draw a regular octagon and the diagonals for one vertex, and then draw a second octagon and the diagonals for a different vertex, these figures are the same up to a rotation.  So if you prove the fact for a single vertex, then it will be true for every vertex because rotations preserve angles; i.e. if you rotate two parallel lines by the same amount, they remain parallel.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Inscribe the octagon on a circle. Can you find the angles between diagonals using the known central angle?

Comment: Is the circle inside the octagon or vise-versa?

Comment: The circle is outside.

Comment: do the octagon and circle share the same center?

Comment: Yes, that is the objective. Since you are working with a regular polygon, with lots of symmetries, a very natural construction is to build the circle with same center as the polygon and that contains its vertices on the circumference. This is the definition of circle circumscribed to a regular polygon.

Comment: Since your question was very basic, I should ask how familiar are you with plane geometry. Are you learning it now? In general it is good to let us know what are your  difficulties so that you can benefit the most from a possible answer.

Comment: My hint is to draw your attention to the possibility of using [inscribed angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). Do you know this result?

Comment: no, does the other answer show the result?